# should I use CLI to transfer C# projects to C++ and Linux?

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

My solution contains many projects all of them are wrote on C#.
I need to transfer entire solution to C++ and Linux. Rewriting all projects will take a lot of time, so I want to do that one by one. I want to start with the most "common" project with basic classes.

I was thinking to start rewritting projects one by one on C++-CLI starting with the most "common" project (the basic project with basic classes that other projects use).

But everything will be finished it seems I will have a lot of CLI code that I assume is not portable to Linux?

So the main question is how intensive should I use CLI taking into account that I will need to run solution on Linux?

I can avoid CLI and replace it for example with zeromq, if it would be better.

**upd** This is HFT trading application, so mono is not acceptable. I want to have pure-c++, gc-free language as I plan to do a lot of optimizations (lock-free code, spin locks, probably using AVX and NUMA etc.)

Comment: is it necessary that you convert to C++ have you considered using migrating them to a Mono project?

Comment: @AntarrByrd no, mono is not acceptale. I need extreme "latency" and GC-free language finally

Comment: so I want to have pure c++, let's not discuss why. I want to discuss how.

Comment: This question makes no sense. C++/CLI is a C++ extension which targets the managed .net platform. Given you want to avoid GC and I assume have low latency your only option is to use an unmanaged language like C++ directly.

Comment: @SimonWood but now I do use C# and .NET. So I need to rewrite projects one by one at the same time keep using solution in production. So I should rewrite to C++ keep using CLR and then finaly, when everything is ready I want to throw away CLR and to migrate to Linux

Comment: Throw away the the CLR? That would be an amazing feat

Comment: or. I can use pure C++ from beggining but then I need to connect them to my C# "not rewritten yet" projects using for example zeromq

Comment: My completely unscientific opinion: I think you will be better off simply doing a direct translation of the application to your pure c++ target, since you're going to wind up eventually rewriting everything anyway.

Comment: @RobertHarvey i just can rewrote anything in one move. i need to rewrite project by project. probably I should use CLI... but not too much.

Answer (score 1):

the c++/CLI is Microsoft specific. It will not be portable. Also you will not get rid of the GC since the GC is a feature of the framework and not the language. C++/CLI is just another .net language with native code combined.

If you really can't use mono then tough luck. You will have to rewrite everything.

Comment: it's ok to keep using CLR ad GC while rewriting. I want to avoid GC and CLR as a final stage. But I need many iterations. Rewrite projects one by one to C++ keep using them with C# projects and only when all projects are rewritten - throw CLR away and go to Linux.

Comment: @javapowered Transferring logic from C# to C++ is easy. But you will have to replace all the CLR API with either your own or with third party libs. That's the hard part. If you want to start with C++/CLI and replace APIs slowly you can do it - however you should notice that the syntax is different too - for instance in CLI you will write String^ someStr and if you transfer it to std::string you will write std::string & someStr. So you will have a lot of work there. And you will have lot of code to interact between managed and native to cleanup later. I'm not sure that's what I would have done.

Comment: so it seems I should minimize using CLI and try to write as much as possible on pure c++

Comment: @javapowered I would suggest to keep CLI to minimum. You will have a lot of non standard language structures to clean up if you don't. If you need to continue using a project from C# I suggest P/Invoke. BTW why not use mono and just transfer time or resource critical code to C++ and call it with p/invoke?

Comment: @javapowered Notice that if you do as I suggest and use mono with p/invoke you can start working on your target platform right away and see if really your assumption that you can't use mono holds up

Comment: i need to call native call (from 3rd party dlls) intensive. this part have to be ported to c++. I will probably use another language for the rest, but i'm not sure what can I use on Linux takingt into account that I really care about latency.

Comment: I'm thinking about starting with mono. rewrite only criticaly parts to C++ and use mono for the rest. But i'm not sure about P/Invoke. Probably zeromq can be used...

Comment: @javapowered If it's all within the same process use p/invoke - It will be faster and easier to read and use. If you write it correctly you will see very little overhead

Comment: i'm afraid pinvoke is pretty slow http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/253444/PInvoke-Performance

Comment: @javapowered I use p/invoke extensively. Performance depends very much on how you do it. Did you read all the comments on the article you posted? CLI may be faster but it's not portable and in my opinion a waist of time since you will have to rewrite everything anyway. In every code there are performance critical parts and others that are not so. Write you code so the logic is written in C# and the algorithms are written in C++, Can you write your code so that you don't do a lot of calls to p/invoke, if not write the p/invoke correctly, You will be OK. Are you happy with your performance now?

Comment: @javapowered Also I recommend doing your own test on your target platform and only then decide to undertake the huge task of rewriting everything in C++

Comment: 100000 other folks already tested and it's known that critical parts should be written using native code